# Connect to a remote postgresql database from oracle linux 8

Tags: postgresql, oraclelinux

I'm running an Oracle Linux 8 instance which I connect to via ssh public key authentication. There I've installed PostgreSQL but I can't seem to access it locally (from DBeaver for example).

I've made these following changes:

[set listen_addreses to '*' at the postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBkHD.png)

[added "host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 md5" at the end of pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QeQx.png)

I added postgresql to the firewall by running

> sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql --permanent

> sudo firewall-cmd --reload

I even tried disabling the firewall with

> sudo systemctl stop firewalld

> sudo systemctl disable firewalld

without any success.

And of course I restarted postgresql after the changes with

> sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service

However nothing was successful. I've had success by making these changes on other servers previously, but not this time.

[And yes postgresql is definitely running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1q30.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
Error message:

```
OperationalError: connection to server at "<ip address>", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Connection details:

Comment: Please share the connection details and error message

Comment: "I can't seem to access it locally"   Everything is local to itself.  From which "local" thing you trying to access it?  Local to your keyboard, or local to the db server?  Since you have gone out of your way to censor the IP address, I assume it was not simply '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: @jjanes Hi, and yes, the censored IP address is the one from the remote server. I just want to access the data from the server to let's say DBeaver or with psycopg2 when i'm working outside of the .server.

Comment: There is still a firewall between your client and the server causing problems.  You may have turned off one firewall, but it was not the only one.